# How can I get the complete source code as a string out of a statement object with the help of clang?

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

I am searching for a way to get the correct source string out of a statement object. My goal is to add a line like "_assign(&var, __ LINE __ );" after every assignment to a variable. So I want to instrument something like

```
x = 42;
```

with

```
x = 42; _assign(&x, __ LINE __);
```

I already found a usefull way to get a statement as string...

```
                    Stmt* s = aStatement;
                    SourceRange sr = s->getSourceRange();
                    string result = Lexer::getSourceText(CharSourceRange::getCharRange(sr), TheRewriter.getSourceMgr(), LangOptions(), 0);
```

...but the results aren't as expected.
If I output all BinaryOperator statements as discribed above, I get something uncomplete linke...

```
SOURCE                        -> CLANG RESULT

*len_p = len;                 -> *len_p =
this->is_empty = tm_true;     -> this->is_empty =
i = start_index / 8;          -> i = start_index /
a_p = &(this->table_p[i]);    -> a_p = &(this->table_p[i]
```

Maybe I am working with the wrong functions...
I have already tried to get the right source location with the help of SourceLocation objects but it ends up in unmaintainable code.

So do anyone know a way of getting the complete statement?

Please help me. :)

Comment: Any achievements ?